# How to debug OpenWRT Chaos Calmer 15.05 configuration files?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, openwrt

A long time ago, I setup a Barrier Breaker OpenWRT router, and configured it for separate vlans with a WAN, DMZ, and LAN respectively.

Well, that said there needs to be an upgrade to the router, so I purchased an identical one and threw Chaos Calmer 15.05 on it, and now I'm trying to configure it so I can daftly swap it out when my family is out of the house.

I noticed that mention was made in the docs that there are now two formats for configuring networking; the old format which I used before and the new format used with swconfig, which I, and it seems the OpenWRT wiki, are somewhat unfamilar with.

I did my best to configure it, and thew my new trusty `Buffalo WZR-HP-G300NH` into safemode to make sure that I could telnet in when something would go wrong...and all of that works, but the configuration isn't giving up it's secrets as to where I messed up with the new swconfig fangle format.  Where do the error logs write out in a persistent manner that I might read of their complaints and fix their issues with my config?

The repo is here: https://github.com/leeand00/chaoCalmerConfig

Comment: swconfig is just about the switch though? Please provide both the old and new configuration for us to check.

Comment: Okay well I'm starting slow, I'm just trying to get a DMZ and vlan going first...so I'll post what I changed from the original okay?  I'm following this wiki article: https://wiki.openwrt.org/doc/howto/dmz

Comment: Here I added the repo, so you can easily see what I changed.  There are only like 4 commits.

Comment: When I restart networking it freezes and then I have to use safemode again...so short of using a serial cable this a bit difficult to trouble shoot.

Comment: Well there is no persistent log, so you'll have to figure it out manually. Also I recommend rebooting when changing low-level settings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, in this case the answer is easy: The interface names are wrong. It's always called ethX.N on OpenWrt.

I recommend restoring the default configuration. It will already have a single VLAN set up. By default it contains all switch ports.

Start from there, first creating a network (connected to nothing). If that works, create the corresponding VLAN in the switch section. Always adapt existing configuration.

Comment: Yeah that `ethX.N` and `ethX_N` business is a little bit confusing...as I'm not sure I understand how that relates to the switch....what do you mean by a network connected to nothing?

Comment: Just create a `config interface` section without changing the switch configuration. Baby steps, so to say. 

Comment: Found something related (haven't tried anything yet), but....https://wiki.openwrt.org/toh/buffalo/wzr-hp-g300h#after_vlan_setup_router_is_inaccessible

Comment: it looks like vlan0 is a no-no

Comment: Yeah, that’s right. It may be missing from some router pages in the wiki though. 4095 is usually not possible either.